# accessing python dict with function values

Tags: python, function, dictionary

I am trying to make a menu of options in python where if the user selects a number a different function is executed:

```
def options(x):
    return {
        1: f1(),
        2: f2()
    }[x]

def f1():
    print "hi"

def f2():
    print "bye"
```

However, well I call

```
options(1)
```

I get:

```
hi
bye
```

and same when I call `options(2)`

What is going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are invoking the functions instead of assiging them against the keys

```
def f1():
  print "hi"

def f2():
  print "bye"

functions = {1: f1, 2: f2}  # dict of functions (Note: no parenthesis)

def options(x):
    return functions[x]()   # Get the function against the index and invoke it

options(1)
# hi

options(2)
# bye
```

Answer (score 1):

Your dictionary is built with the *return values* of the functions; don't call the function until after picking it from the dict:

```
def options(x):
    return {
        1: f1,
        2: f2
    }[x]()
```

Now you are storing just a reference to the functions in the dictionary, and call the selected function *after* retrieving it.

Demo:

```
>>> def f1():
...     print "hi"
... 
>>> def f2():
...     print "bye"
... 
>>> def options(x):
...     return {
...         1: f1,
...         2: f2
...     }[x]()
... 
>>> options(1)
hi
>>> options(2)
bye
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace print with return and return with, then it will work. Or use thefourtheye version.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you call the functions (with `()`) while you are building the dictionary. Leave the parens off and apply them later only after getting the value from the dictionary:

```
def options(x):
    return {
        1: f1,
        2: f2
    }[x]()
```